# How to run multiple .py file from one .py file in python

Tags: python, import, python-import

I'm new to python, I have three python script
pyapp_1.py , pyapp_2.py ,pyapp_3.py in same dir . I want to make a file like run.py where I take input from user like this:

```
press 1 to run pyapp_1.py 
press 2 to run pyapp_2.py 
press 3 to run pyapp_3.py
```

if user press 1 only pyapp_1.py should run .

how can i do this,
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
x=int(input("press 1 to run pyapp_1.py\npress 2 to run pyapp_2.py\npress 3 to run pyapp_3.py"))
if x==1:
    import pyapp_1
elif x==2:
    import pyapp_2
elif x==3:
    import pyapp_3
```

Answer (score 2):

Put you code in function, import the code into a new file like main.py

main.py

```
import file1.py
import file2.py
import file3.py

while true: 
  x=input()

  if (x == 1): 
     file1()
  if (x == 2):
     file2()
  if (x == 3):
     file3()
```

Answer (score 1):

For running a python script example:

```
import runpy
runpy.run_path(path_name='pyapp_x.py')
```

If you use Python 3.10 or higher:

```
x=int(input("Please insert a number bewtween 1 and 3: "))

match x:
    case 1:
        runpy.run_path(path_name='pyapp_1.py')
    case 2: 
        runpy.run_path(path_name='pyapp_2.py')
    case 3:  
        runpy.run_path(path_name='pyapp_3.py')
    case _:
        print(f'Error: {x} is not between 1 and 3')
```